# Transfer images from android device to pc using WiFi

Tags: android

I want to transfer images and files from Android SD Card to PC Server(FTTP Server) using wifi connection? kindly help me if you can......I will appreciate your time and help

Comment: HI.. Did you find any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/40.html) is an example on how to use a wifi connection, from here, you need to use commons ftp to transfer file.

there is an [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949819/trying-to-make-my-android-application-put-files-on-my-ftp-server) similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

There are some free apps available that can be used for this. One is SwiFTP: https://market.android.com/details?id=org.swiftp&hl=en

Hope this helps! I couldn't determine from the question whether you'd like to code this kind of app yourself or simply use it to transfer the files.

Comment: Respected Roger!
I want to take images from my android tablets until its memory is full, than want to send these images to my PC wirelessly(WiFi), i want to do this programatically, any help?